# What determines if a data type is an object or a primitive data type in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have read that the `null` data type in JavaScript is a primitive data type, however due to a bug or something in the first version JavaScript, `null` is considered to be an object.

However, let's assume that `null` is a real object (and not a primitive data type like it really is), what does that mean exactly, i.e. what does a data type being an object mean exactly?

For example if a data type is an object, does that mean that attributes and methods can be added to instances of that data type, while a primitive data type can't have attributes and methods added to its instances? and so the reasosn why `null` is really a primitive data type and not an object is because you can't add attributes and methods to its instances?

Answer (score 3):

From the [ECMAScript 2020 specification](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types):

> The ECMAScript language types are Undefined, Null, Boolean, String, Symbol, Number, BigInt, and Object.

And also:

> The Null type has exactly one value, called null.
>
> An Object is logically a collection of properties.

Null and Object are two different data types because that's how the spec is written. The specific bug that you are referring to is the fact that `typeof null` returns "object" even though it was [originally intended to return "null"](https://2ality.com/2013/10/typeof-null.html), and this has been [retained in the specification](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-typeof-operator) for backward compatibility.

To answer the second half of your question, objects are the only type that can have properties directly defined on them. However, since JavaScript is a prototype-based language, you can still augment other types (except Undefined and Null) with custom attributes and methods through their prototype. For example:

```
var x = 10; // x is a Number
x.foo = 20; // doesn't work since x is not an Object

// Number.prototype is an Object, so you can add properties to it
Number.prototype.foo = 30;
Number.prototype.bar = function() { return 40; }

x.foo; // returns 30
x.bar(); // returns 40
```